# Asp.net Dictionary - Replace hard coded values with database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I'm trying to implement this tag cloud:
http://thetagcloud.codeplex.com/

...and I need the replace the hard-coded values below with those coming from my database?

```
    <%= new TagCloud(   new Dictionary<string, int> {
                        {"C#", 58},
                        {"ASP.NET", 45},
                        {"VB.NET", 36},
                        {"AJAX", 24},
                        {"LINQ", 13}
                    },
                    new TagCloudGenerationRules
                    {
                        TagToolTipFormatString = "Tag weight: {0}",
                        TagUrlFormatString = "search.aspx?p=1&tag={0}"
                    }) %>
```

I've created the following sql string which returns the data in the format expected string/int or value/key

```
SELECT Tag, COUNT(Tag) AS Counter
FROM         dbo.CtagCloud
GROUP BY Tag
HAVING      (COUNT(Tag) > 3)
ORDER BY Counter DESC
```

Comment: Can you post the data access code you have?

Comment: I think you will need to modify your query so that it returns the id associated with the tag as well (58,45,36,24,13) in addition to the tag name and the count.

Comment: Hi, I've added my data access code below.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my data access code

```
 // SQL Select Command
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand mySqlSelect = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT Tag, COUNT(Tag) AS Counter FROM dbo.CtagCloud GROUP BY Tag HAVING (COUNT(Tag) > 3) ORDER BY Counter DESC", conn);
    mySqlSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter mySqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlSelect);
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    mySqlAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

    // create an instance for ArrayList
    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

    // foreach loop to read each DataRow of DataTable stored inside the DataSet
    foreach (DataRow dRow in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        // add DataRow object to ArrayList
        myArrayList.Add(dRow);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hmm,** I've had a *super* brief look, just glazing over that sample code. I suspect you need to pass in an Array (value pairs) not a string.

Just loop through each records returned and add it to an array. Then pass that array into the TagCloud object.